# Bottom 3 values for each row in R

Tags: r

The program below returns closest match of a word by finding it in the other list. I want 3 close matches instead of closest match.

```
source1.devices = data.frame(name = c("Galaxy S5",
                    "Samsung Galaxy S4",
                    "Samsung Galaxy S4 schwarz",
                    "Samsung GALAXY Note 4",
                    "Samsung GALAXY Tab T535 schwarz",
                    "Samsung Galaxy S4 mini weiÃŸ",
                    "iPhone 5S 16GB Gold",
                    "iPad Air 2 Gold Tastatur Schwarz",
                    "iPad Air 2 Gold & Kensington "), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

source2.devices = data.frame(name = c("Galaxy S5 & Galaxy Tab 3 7.0 Lite",
                    "Samsung Galaxy S4 Black Edition",
                    "Samsung Galaxy S4 mini schwarz",
                    "Samsung GALAXY Note 4",
                    "Samsung Galaxy S4 mini weiÃŸ",
                    "iPhone 5S 16GB Gold",
                    "iPad Air 2 Gold & Kensington Tastatur Schwarz",
                    "Samsung Galaxy S5 weiÃŸ",
                    "iPhone 6 64 GB Gold",
                    "iPhone 6 16 GB Silber") , stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


library(stringdist)

distance.methods<-c('jw')
dist.methods<-list()
for(m in 1:length(distance.methods))
{
  dist.name.enh<-matrix(NA, ncol = length(source2.devices$name),nrow = length(source1.devices$name))
  for(i in 1:length(source2.devices$name)) {
    for(j in 1:length(source1.devices$name)) { 
      dist.name.enh[j,i]<-stringdist(tolower(source2.devices[i,"name"]),tolower(source1.devices[j,"name"]),method = distance.methods[m])      
    }  
  }
  dist.methods[[distance.methods[m]]]<-dist.name.enh
}

match.s1.s2.enh<-NULL
for(m in 1:length(dist.methods))
{

  dist.matrix<-as.matrix(dist.methods[[distance.methods[m]]])
  min.name.enh<-apply(dist.matrix, 1, base::min)
  for(i in 1:nrow(dist.matrix))
  {
    s2.i<-match(min.name.enh[i],dist.matrix[i,])
    s1.i<-i
    match.s1.s2.enh<-rbind(data.frame(s2.i=s2.i,s1.i=s1.i,s2name=source2.devices[s2.i,"name"], s1name=source1.devices[s1.i,"name"], adist=min.name.enh[i],method=distance.methods[m]),match.s1.s2.enh)
  }
}

match.s1.s2.enh
```

In the above code, it is using min() function to find the minimum distance in dist.matrix (closest match). I am able to code to get 3 close values using the following code -

```
dist.matrix = data.frame(dist.matrix)
df2=data.frame(t(apply(dist.matrix,1,function(x) names(x)[order(x,na.last=NA)][1:3])))
colnames(df2)=c(paste0("Ranked",c(1:3)))
df2
```

I am finding difficulty in implementing this code in the main program. I want output to look like below -

```
Name                 Rank1                          Rank2           Rank3  
Samsung Galaxy S4   Samsung Galaxy S4 mini weiÃŸ  Samsung Galaxy Note4 Samsung Galaxy S4 mini schwarz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### tidyverse solution

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringdist)
```

Make matrix of string distances (row = `source1.devices`, column = `source2.devices`)

```
M <- as.data.frame(stringdistmatrix(source1.devices$name, source2.devices$name, method="jw"))
```

Make data.frame containing top 3 nearest strings using `map_df`

```
nearest <- map_df(1:nrow(M), ~data.frame(name=source1.devices$name[.x],
                                         key=paste0("Rank", 1:ncol(M)),
                                     val=source2.devices$name[order(M[.x,])],
                                         stringsAsFactors=F) %>%
                                 slice(1:3))
```

`spread` into wide format

```
ans <- nearest %>%
         group_by(name) %>%
         spread(key, val)
```

#### Output

```
 ans[6,]  # Samsung Galaxy S4

               name                     Rank1                          Rank2
1 Samsung Galaxy S4 "Samsung Galaxy S5 weiÃŸ" "Samsung Galaxy S4 mini weiÃŸ"
# ... with 1 more variables: Rank3 <chr>
```

Comment: Elegant Solution! Thanks a ton :)

Comment: Can we keep original order of first list? Ordering of values has changed in the final answer.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why that's happened. Could you try
 `ans[match(source1.devices$name, ans$name),]`?